# Returning a value based on multiple conditions in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Consider the following data:

```
 Item | Overall | Individual | newColumn
 A    | Fail    | Pass       | blank
 A    | Fail    | Fail       | blank
 B    | Fail    | Pass       | issue
 B    | Fail    | Pass       | issue
 C    | Pass    | Pass       | blank
```

I have the logic built out for the first 3 columns already. There are two levels of fails in this data:

1. overall, and
2. individual.

If any of the individual fail, the overall fails. Sometimes the overall can fail even though all the individuals are fine. This logic is already built out.

I am trying to find a formula for the `newColumn`. If **all** the individuals are a pass for a given item (example item B), but the overall is still a fail, the cell should return the text "issue". It is ok if it returns issue twice, not sure if you can non-dupe that part. I've tried various forms of countifs/and/ors and creating columns that count distinct values but I always find a scenario where it will break the logic.

Comment: i think when u try to explain your logic, avoid using "Sometimes..." its not logic.

Comment: @Rosetta This worksheet has lots of tabs that aggregate data that produce the overall fail column. In those tabs there are many different criteria, sometimes judgement based, that feed into the fail result. That is why I said sometimes the Overall can fail even though all the individuals pass (i felt that if i didn't say that then someone here may try to question the pass/fails). I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: no worries, it is just my 2 cents. thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,A2,$C$2:$C$6,"Fail"),"blank",IF(B2="Fail","Issue","blank"))
```

As required

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new column with the formula:

```
=IF(B2="Fail",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"fail")=0,"issue",""),"")
```

Then this should work on the assumptions:

- For each item if one of the overalls are false they are all false
- The only two possible values are "Pass" and "Fail" for columns B & C

If you require the word blank instead of a blank cell then use:

```
=IF(B2="Fail",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"fail")=0,"issue","blank"),"blank")
```